# Как установить две версии пакета в одном package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

В проекте временно нужно чтобы был установлен `bootstrap 4` и `bootstrap 5`. Проблема в том, что по умолчанию они устанавливаются в одну и ту же директорию `node-modules/bootstrap` .

```
bootstrap 4: npm install bootstrap
bootstrap 5: npm install bootstrap@next
```

Реально ли установить `bootstrap 5` в директорию `node-modules/bootstrap5`? Если да, то как?

Нашел вариант с префиксом `npm install --prefix ./bootstrap5 bootstrap@next` -  но тут создается новая директория node-modules и возникают свои проблемы с импортом компонент.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Реально. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install

> `npm install <alias>@npm:<name>`

Т.е. в вашем случае: `npm install bootstrap5@npm:bootstrap@next`

Но в таком случае все ваши файлы которые хотят пятый бутстрап должны явно писать `require('bootstrap5')` (или `import ... from 'bootstrap5'`).